# How can i find the 4th height Salary in a Employee object in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

Hi **Can any one tell me how to find the 5th highest salary in a employee object?**

Suppose they are 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000,5000, 6000, 7000,80000 these are the salary how to find 5th most highest salary.

Comment: in apex? soql? report? what have you tried so far? there's no standard employee object in SF, do you mean Contact with some custom fields? Do you know how LIMIT & OFFSET works in SOQL?

Comment: I mean employee object is custom object can you suggest me in both apex and soql how can we achieve it?

Comment: Is that a job interview challenge? ;) you won't get very far this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic query would look similar to this (I don't have your object in my org and since you didn't put enough effort in the question - you'll have to adapt the answer)

```
select name, numberofemployees
from account
order by numberofemployees desc nulls last
limit 5
```

[image]

Then to really get only 5th row you'd do

```
select name, numberofemployees
from account
order by numberofemployees desc nulls last
limit 1 offset 4
```

This gets trickier if there are duplicates and for example in your data 7000 would appear twice, that still counts as 2nd highest. Then probably something like this is needed

```
select numberofemployees, count(id)
from account
group by numberofemployees
order by numberofemployees desc nulls last
limit 1 offset 4
```